# Try to Find and Replace in Formulas in Last Line Data

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the last line of data, copy it with formulas to the row below it and then do a find and replace on the new last row - I got it to copy the line down but the find and replace isnt working - any tips? Thanks.

```
Sub CopyLastRowandReplace()

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ReplaceRow As Range

Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Book 1")
    
LastRow = sourceSheet.Range("B" & sourceSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("B" & LastRow & ":N" & LastRow)
    
sourceRange.Offset(1).Formula = sourceRange.Formula

Set ReplaceRow = sourceSheet.Range("B" & LastRow & ":N" & LastRow)

Range("B" & LastRow & ":N" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.Replace What:="Aug", Replacement:="Sep", LookAt:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: `ReplaceRow.Replace What:="Aug"....`

Comment: Tried that already - kept getting "subscript out of range" error. Thanks for the reponse.

Comment: On what line? That line shouldn't throw a subscript out of range error. If anything, `Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Book 1")` would.

Comment: No idea thats why the question - it copies the line I need down fine just the F&R isn't being picked up even though i though i defined the range accurately - its just the new last line on the data set

Comment: The parameter `LookAt` usually has arguments like `xlWhole` (1) and `xlPart` (2), while the parameter `LookIn` of the `Find method` has arguments like `xlFormulas`, `xlValues` and `xlComments` which are totally different than 1 or 2.

Comment: It just says application or object defined error - not sure where thats even coming from now

Answer (score 0):

Core problems

1. `LookAt:=xlFormulas`.  Sould be `xlPart` or `xlWhole`
2. You are not Replacing in the *New* last row (you haven't updated LastRow)

That said, there are other oportunities for improvement too

```vb
Sub Demo()
    CopyLastRowandReplace ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Book 1"), 2, 13, "Aug", "Sep"
End Sub

Sub CopyLastRowandReplace(sourceSheet As Worksheet, StartColumn As Long, NumColumns As Long, FindValue As Variant, ReplaceValue As Variant)
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, StartColumn).End(xlUp).Resize(1, NumColumns)
        
    With sourceRange
        .Offset(1, 0).Formula = .Formula
    
        .Offset(1, 0).Replace _
          What:=FindValue, _
          Replacement:=ReplaceValue, _
          LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
          MatchCase:=True, _
          SearchFormat:=False, _
          ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes this worked awesome - thank you. Can i ask why this is better/an improvement compared to my code? Im always looking to understand why my code is bad haha. Thanks.

Comment: 1) avoids Select 2) avoids string building in the range definitions 3) concentrates the range definition onto one line, makes it safer to update later if required.  You could also generalise the Find and Replace values, to make it more easily reusable.

Comment: What do you mean generalize - b/c I'm going to have to do this identical above process to 40+ other sheets. - Are you saying to define it as a variable/string and set the F&R with that?

Comment: I've updated the code to a parameterised version you can call with different values  as required